# Do not allow the creation of an administrator remotely

Tags: admin, hacked

Two of our websites suddenly have admin accounts that were created remotely, according to the logs. I also found the code that created it. Is there a way to defend against this?

Comment: It's not possible for admin accounts to be created remotely. If that has happened then your site has been compromised and your suggested solution will not work, because if the hacker has sufficient access to create admin users then they also have access to bypass any code you put in their way. What code did you find that created it?

Comment: Yes, the site was apparently compromised. I do not want to post the code on Internet to help other hackers. But this is the log entry of Wordfence: "An admin user with the username xxxxxx was created outside of WordPress." Apparently there is a way to get in remotly. I am not sure why you lowerd the question rating. I wanted to help others.

Comment: I just want to add that the code I provided works. If the hacker creates an admin account again, he will not be able to log in as admin. The hacker code was in the functions.php of the parent theme. Somehow he was able to add it at the end, probably using upload, because I found the suspicious code in the uploads. I believe I managed to limit the upload to just images for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short script that prevents unapproved admins from logging in. Of course it is possible to add multiple login names.

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'auth_signon', 30, 3 );
function auth_signon( $user, $username, $password ) {
    if( strtoupper($username) !== 'MYLOGINNAME' && in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles )){
         wp_logout();
         return new WP_Error( 'broke', __( $username . ", good try, but you are not an administrator"  , "text_domain" ) );
        exit;
    }else{
        return $user;   
    }
}
```